# TikZ - Remove space around nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm relatively new to TikZ and I drew the following graph. However, there is some space around the filled black node. Is there a way to have the lines actually connecting with the node?

EDIT: I'm not sure why it doesn't compile and show the graph in here? Maybe someone could please help me with this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\node (1) at (0.4, 2.2) [circle,draw] {1};
\node (4) at (0.4, 0.6) [circle,draw] {4};
\node (3) at (2.6, 0.6) [circle,draw] {3};
\node (7) at (1.5,1.5) {};
\node (2) at (2.6, 2.2) [circle,draw] {2};

\fill (7) circle (2.5pt);

\draw[-] (1) to (7);
\draw[-] (4) to (7);
\draw[-] (3) to (7);
\draw[-] (2) to (7);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The code you upload here doesn't get compiled automatically. What you can do is upload a picture of the results yourself. You'll have to convert the pdf to something else (png or jpeg should be fine).

Comment: Thank you! I've added a picture for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can control the space added with the `inner sep` key:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\node (1) at (0.4, 2.2) [circle,draw] {1};
\node (4) at (0.4, 0.6) [circle,draw] {4};
\node (3) at (2.6, 0.6) [circle,draw] {3};
\node[inner sep=0pt] (7) at (1.5,1.5) {};
\node (2) at (2.6, 2.2) [circle,draw] {2};

\fill (7) circle (2.5pt);

\draw[-] (1) to (7);
\draw[-] (4) to (7);
\draw[-] (3) to (7);
\draw[-] (2) to (7);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I also have another graph as the one above only that there are two black nodes and a line in the middle. If I add [inner sep=0pt] as you suggested to both nodes, the middle line however appears to be darker than the rest - is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: @SallyOwens that might be a problem of the rendering of your PDF viewer. You could try to zoom in more on that line to really check that. Or use another viewer (xpdf is known to be very precise in rendering).

Comment: Thank you - this migth be the problem. When zooming in, they all appear equally dark/bold :) I just wanted to check that it is no a problem caused by my code.

Answer (score 7):

You are already using circular node shapes, so why not here? And you can put the filled circle in the middle with `barycentric cs:` (but since you are naming the ones 1, 2, 3, 4, the syntax is here a bit amusing, which is the main reason why I am posting this ;-). And `\foreach` can make your life easier.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\node (1) at (0.4, 2.2) [circle,draw] {1};
\node (4) at (0.4, 0.6) [circle,draw] {4};
\node (3) at (2.6, 0.6) [circle,draw] {3};
\node (2) at (2.6, 2.2) [circle,draw] {2};
\node[inner sep=2.5pt,circle,fill] (7) at (barycentric cs:1=1,2=1,3=1,4=1) {};

\foreach \X in {1,...,4}
{\draw[-] (\X) to (7);}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for `barycentric` coordinates. it is very, very rare visible here :-)

Comment: @Zarko Thanks! (I actually posted it because of `2=1`. If one would use `\node[inner sep=2.5pt,circle,fill] (7) at (barycentric cs:1=1,2=2,3=3,4=4) {};` instead, it wouldn't work. ;-)

Comment: This question draws the attention of all TikZ association stakeholders.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\node (1) at (0.4, 2.2) [circle,draw] {1};
\node (4) at (0.4, 0.6) [circle,draw] {4};
\node (3) at (2.6, 0.6) [circle,draw] {3};
\node (7) at (1.5,1.5) {};
\node (2) at (2.6, 2.2) [circle,draw] {2};

\node[circle, fill=black, draw=black, minimum size=2.5pt] (7) at (1.5, 1.4) {};

\draw[-] (1) to (7);
\draw[-] (4) to (7);
\draw[-] (3) to (7);
\draw[-] (2) to (7);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You forgot `\begin{document}` and you should use a node for the circle as well, where you specify the size and color in the node properties.

Comment: For an equivalent to `circle(2.5pt)`, minimum size should be 5pt. And you need to fix `inner sep=0pt` otherwise default inner sep makes a node larger than `5pt`. Finally, `outer sep=0pt` is needed to avoid a little gap between lines and central node. `\node[circle, fill=black, minimum size=5pt, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] (7) at (1.5,1.5) {};`

Comment: Ups sorry, if you also `draw` the node, `outer sep=0pt` is not needed. `\node[circle, draw, fill=black, minimum size=5pt, inner sep=0pt] (7) at (1.5,1.5) {};`

Answer (score 5):

You can define `(7)` as `coordinate` instead of `node` to solve this.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (1) at (0.4, 2.2) [circle,draw] {1};
\node (4) at (0.4, 0.6) [circle,draw] {4};
\node (3) at (2.6, 0.6) [circle,draw] {3};
\coordinate (7) at (1.5,1.5) {};
\node (2) at (2.6, 2.2) [circle,draw] {2};

\fill (7) circle (2.5pt);

\draw (1) to (7);
\draw (4) to (7);
\draw (3) to (7);
\draw (2) to (7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

using polar coordinates and `\foreach` loop make your code simpler and shorter ...

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3.141592mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,
circ/.style = {circle, draw},
 dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=2.5pt}
                        ]
\node (n7) [dot]    {};
\foreach \i [count=\ii] in {135, 45, 315, 225}
\node (\ii) [circ] at (\i:16mm) {\ii};
\draw (1) -- (3)    (2) -- (4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I would like to join the celebration by offering an additional solution!

The middle node `(7)` is defined when drawing the first diagonal `(1)--(3)`.

```
\draw (1) -- (3) node [midway,fill] (7){};
```

I also factorized the style applied to the nodes with the key `every node/.style={circle,draw}`

[image: capture]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8,every node/.style={circle,draw}]]
\node (1) at (0.4, 2.2) {1};
\node (4) at (0.4, 0.6) {4};
\node (3) at (2.6, 0.6) {3};
\node (2) at (2.6, 2.2) {2};
\draw (1) -- (3) node [midway,fill] (7){};
\draw (2) to (7)to (4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 since the 4 edges are aligned, that is, 3 nodes are colinear.

Answer (score 2):

You can write `\draw (1)--(7.center)`. 
[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (1) at (0.4, 2.2) [circle,draw] {1};
\node (4) at (0.4, 0.6) [circle,draw] {4};
\node (3) at (2.6, 0.6) [circle,draw] {3};
\node (7) at (1.5,1.5) {};
\node (2) at (2.6, 2.2) [circle,draw] {2};

\fill (7) circle (2.5pt);

\draw (1) to (7.center);
\draw (4) to (7.center);
\draw (3) to (7.center);
\draw (2) to (7.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```