# Node spacing in TexLive 2023

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

As far as I know (and from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/460254/241755)), in previous versions of TexLive, it was enough to set `inner sep=0pt` to have a node with no spacing. But in TexLive 2023, it seems that this is not enough. I also tried to set `outer sep=0pt` but again it shows some smaller spacing. How to get ride of this space and fill that triangle?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
            \draw[red] (-4,4) .. controls (-1,0) and (1.5,12) .. (4,4)
            node[pos=0.6,inner sep = 0pt,outer sep=0](a){}
            node[pos=0.65,inner sep = 0pt,outer sep=0](b){};
            \node[inner sep = 0pt,outer sep=0](c) at (1,4){};
        \filldraw[draw=blue, fill=blue](a)--(b)--(c)--(a);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: which space do you want to change? what result does this example make  in texlive 2022?

Comment: my problem is same as in the linked post. in picture, it is clear that nodes produce space.

Comment: Does using: `\draw[draw=blue, join=round](a.center)--(b.center)--(c.center)--cycle;` solve your issue. I changed it to draw so that we can see the corners.

Comment: No more space between blue lines using `minimum size=0`... But the fill operation still fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know what was changes in the TexLive 2023, however use coordinates instead of nodes is to my opinion better (correct) way to draw your blue line:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
            \draw[red] (-4,4) .. controls (-1,0) and (1.5,12) .. (4,4)
            coordinate[pos=0.6]    (a)
            coordinate[pos=0.65]   (b);
            \coordinate            (c) at (1,4);
        \draw[draw=blue](a)--(b)--(c)--cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Thanks for you solution. I postpone accepting the answer until someone can explain the change in TL 2023.

Comment: Your problem appear also at use of the recent MiKTeX installation of LaTeX. Apparently both use novel version of packages (in your case `tikz` version 3..1.10 from Januar 15, 20023), which contain some bug fixes and/or defined new features, preferable syntax and more consistent code. Anyway, in your case the use of coordinates instead of nodes was recommended in all `tikz` version.

Comment: I've never used "coordinates" because it was a bit confusing (when I started tikz 8 years ago) So I was afraid to use it. I still prefer @PeterGrill comment because of my background!

Comment: @C.F.G all is up to you. You still can stick to used approach which is problematic (gives incorrect result) instead to simple solve your problem with use of coordinates where they supposed to be just coordinates. BTW, for nodes, for which you like that behave as coordinates, you can use the following: `\node[pos=..., coordinates] (<name of coordinate>) {}; ` .

Comment: @C.F.G Peter Gill‘s suggestion to use anchors such as `a.center` does nothing different than using coordinates, since an anchor typically points to a coordinate.